# Meaning of statemment in Angular

Tags: javascript

I got an existing Angular project. I saw some confusing code there, e.g.:

```
let vals;
let cons = callFunction()[vals];
```

Can anyone help me to understand these lines of code?

Comment: Without more context, there is not much to say. What is the issue? What is `callFunction`? What does it return? Is `vals` really undefined.... etc

Comment: It's just accessing a property in an object returned by a function. I.E. `let vals = 'foo'; let cons = function ( ) { return { foo: 'bar' }; }()[vals]; // cons === 'bar'`

Comment: It's the same as `let cons = callFunction().undefined;` - probably not what was intended.